# c# wrong number when calculating percentage

Tags: c#, double, decimal, percentage

trying to calculate and subtract the price of something, but keeps coming up wrong, and adds an extra 500m to it and cannot understand why.

here is my code

```
        var discountPercentage = 50 / 100;
        discountedPrice= (decimal)(discountPercentage * 150000M + 10000M +  0);
```

the answer keeps giving me 85000.0M where it should be 80000, which is half of the combined amount (150000M + 10000M)

Comment: What is the value of `discountPercentage`? It's not clear from your code what value it could hold.

Comment: What is `var discountPercentage =  / 100;` really supposed to be?

Comment: Also, your result will be `(discountPercentage * 150000M) + 10000M`, not `discountPercentage * (150000M + 10000M)`. Is it possible that that's the mistake you're making?

Comment: please provide a *complete* example demonstrating the issue

Comment: apologies i have edited

Comment: `discountPercentage` is using a result of integer division.

Comment: Basic maths PEMDAS/BODMAS rules : it is because the multiplication is calculated first before the addition. In other words : `(discountPercentage * 150000M) + 10000M` is not mathematically the same as `discountPercentage * (150000M + 10000M)`.

Comment: Also I would write:  `var discountPercentage =  50M/100M;`  instead of  `var discountPercentage = 50/100;` to be more precise in the calculus.

Comment: `50/100` = 0 (integer division)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your parenthesis are placed wrong in **discountPercentage**. It has to do with priority of operations.

```
discountPercentage * (150000M + 10000M +  0);
```